# Go routines and Defer

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

```
func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("Main defer")
    go t1()
    go t2()
    go t3()
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)

}

func t1() {
    defer fmt.Println("t1 defer")
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
func t2() {
    defer fmt.Println("t2 defer")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    panic(New("T2"))
}
func t3() {
    defer fmt.Println("t3 defer")
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

1 thread (t2) calls panic, t2 defer gets called.
when t2 panics, every other thread is also terminated.
I want every thread's defer to be called. 
It's a scenario where panic is must, panic is in one thread.. So I want every thread to be aware that program is going to exit.
Any approach I can achieve that?

**present output:**

```
t2 defer
panic: T2

goroutine 19 [running]:
main.t2()
        C:/Users/Talha.Irfan/OneDrive - Bentley Systems, Inc/Desktop/go_test/src/main2/main.go:34 +0x105
created by main.main
        C:/Users/Talha.Irfan/OneDrive - Bentley Systems, Inc/Desktop/go_test/src/main2/main.go:21 +0xb0
```

Comment: When `panic` calls your `main` program exists just like `os.Exist`. So you can go for `log.Println()`. What you wanna achieve describe in your post

Comment: it's already described... for now only 1 defer is being called... but there are 3 threads in total.. so I want every defer of each thread to be called

Comment: it's a scenario where panic is must,, panic is in the thread.. so I want every thread to be aware that program is going to exit.

Comment: Ok you can mention it in your post by editing what you wants to achieve and why. Use quit channel to send values to different threads

Comment: ok thank you, i'll look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing will be called after code panics. That's how panic works, your program will exists after panic. You can use channels to send the values to other go routines if panic occurs. One more thing, It is better to use `Wait Groups` to wait for all go routines to finish rather using `time.Sleep`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    defer fmt.Println("Main defer")
    ch := make(chan int)
    wg.Add(1)
    go t1(ch, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go t2(ch, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go t3(ch, &wg)
    ch <- 1
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}

func t1(ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer fmt.Println("t1 defer")
    defer wg.Done()
}

func t2(ch chan int,wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer fmt.Println("t2 defer")
    for {
         foo, ok := <- ch
         if !ok {
                println("done")
                wg.Done()
                return
         }
         println(foo)
    }
}
func t3(ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer fmt.Println("t3 defer")
    defer wg.Done()
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/HiUFy1wZRDX)

In case you are getting an error inside the code you can use recover to catch the error. This will led your code to run all goroutines.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("Main defer")
    go t1()
    go t2()
    go t3()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

}

func t1() {
    defer fmt.Println("t1 defer")
}
func t2() {
    defer fmt.Println("t2 defer")
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                println("panic:" + r.(string))
            }
        }()
}
func t3() {
    defer fmt.Println("t3 defer")
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KyNa6-aAEOf)

Comment: ok, can u give simple example of passing values through channels?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan check the edited answer to send values using channel.